# Prevent User to reload page using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, refresh, reload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent any form of page refresh using jQuery/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527041/prevent-any-form-of-page-refresh-using-jquery-javascript)

how can i prevent user to reload (refresh) html page using javascript or jquery.

after loading the page for the first time, i want to prevent user reload the page either by press F5 or refresh from browser or by any way.

`Can i do that?`

**Note:** i try `window.onbeforeunload`, but i didn't know how to stop window.onload event from it.

Any help?

Comment: This other SO page answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527041/prevent-any-form-of-page-refresh-using-jquery-javascript

Comment: _"using javascript or jquery"_ - Note: if it can't be done with JS then it can't be done with jQuery...

Comment: i know that but i mean that if i can do that by jquery i better for me to do it by javascript

Comment: C0deH4cker, i try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527041/prevent-any-form-of-page-refresh-using-jquery-javascript but after an alert asks me to stay in the page or leave it, if i choose stay it works fine, but if i choose leave it calls th onload event also, and that i don't need it

Comment: @mbayloon you cant stop the page from reloading, if the user wants it to. Check out my answer below..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't. If a user wants to reload a page you cannot stop them.

Answer (score 9):

It is **not possible** to stop the user from page reload/page close if the user wants it. Two methods which you can use are as follows:

***You can ask for a confirmation like this:***

```
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
e = e || window.event;

// For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
if (e) {
    e.returnValue = 'Sure?';
}

// For Safari
return 'Sure?';
};
</script>
```

Here is the fiddle for above: http://jsfiddle.net/gopi1410/NujmL/

***You can preventDefault on pressing of F5 key using:***

```
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
  if(window.event){
        event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Comment: i try your answer, but as i said, my problem is to avoid calling windows.onload

Comment: @mbayloon Thats impossible, as mentioned in both the above answers.