# How to block refresh functionality using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project where the user should not be allowed to refresh the page using any of the following techniques:

Refresh, <kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>... etc.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/q/3527041/988355  It might get you moving in the right direction

Comment: I recommend to find another project - you'll likely be forced to do other not-very-nice-near-to-impossible things...

Answer (score 1):

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (e) {
            document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 116) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            }, false);
  }, false);
```

Its nearly impossible to do such thing, you can prompt user from getting refreshed,

```
  var confirmOnPageExit = function (e) {
// If we haven't been passed the event get the window.event
            e = e || window.event;
            var message = 'Any text will block the navigation and display a prompt';
// For IE6-8 and Firefox prior to version 4
            if (e) {
                e.returnValue = message;
            }
// For Chrome, Safari, IE8+ and Opera 12+
            return message;
        };
        window.onbeforeunload = confirmOnPageExit;
```

Comment: This blocks refreshes by pressing F5, but the OP wants to prevent other methods of refresh too