# Prevent refreshing the page after button clicked in vb.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, vb.net

I have a page with a javascript that dynamically create a controls (radio buttons, text boxes) .

on button (submit) I need to validate the values before proceeding with the event it self .

but , after hitting the button I need to cancel the event if one rule didn't obey. but the page gets refreshed and all my dynamic controls goes so I need to stop any action to a page if one of the rules failed . (save the form)

I believe there is a way such as **e.preventDefault();** in javascript .

Please Advise,
Many Thanks :)

Comment: shows some codes so we could know where are you now. had you tried to `return false` on the button submit callback?

Comment: do you a function that validates the data ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to prevent page refresh But we are not certain what you are talking about, so I'll just Give the regular example That I can Find

Fist your e.preventDefault is not for refresh its just prevent link from opening the URL and i.e  as per w3school

```
      $("a").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Now To prevent a page refresh there are too many example  Please take a look at the Given link [Please take a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527041/prevent-any-form-of-page-refresh-using-jquery-javascript)

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is I need it in the code behind (vb.net) I need something work like break exit sub , to stay on the same page to save my texts that I wrote on the text boxes after all rules valid.

Comment: Then do not allow the postback or use ajax to stay on the page even if the data is send or not

Comment: One more Thing just use the <input> tag of the html instead of the asp button and put the click event using javascript