# Prevent user from refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, refresh, preventdefault

I want to prevent the user from refreshing the page, How to do this? I have been using `e.preventDefault` method but it`s not running properly.

Comment: Please share your work.

Comment: Effectively, you can't. Even if you can, you shouldn't.

Comment: You need to send `e` in your event properly, like this: `$(someElement).someAction(function(e){});` or use `return false` in the end of your method

Comment: Why do you want to break the user's browser functionality?

Comment: @JonStirling thx for the reminder

Comment: this is the point of ajax : Update a web page without reloading the page . http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Comment: Answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3527041/632951

Comment: The answers here (and on similar questions) all have the javascript `onbeforeunload` event to prevent someone from leaving a page. But what about ONLY nagging about a reload? Can I see where the browser is trying to go? And only alert the user if they are going to my site again? It's a dynamic status page, I don't want people constantly reloading when that's unnecessary. But I don't want to bug them if they are simply leaving.

Comment: I feel like scammers who scam the lives out of people by changing the page's HTML will use this to their advantage.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the window.onbeforeunload even.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
            return "you can not refresh the page";
        }
```

Comment: window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
    event.returnValue = "Write something clever here..";
};

Comment: Reason for not being supported  : https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/chrome-51-deprecations?hl=en#remove-custom-messages-in-onbeforeload-dialogs

Comment: I tried this method window.onbeforeunload = function(event) { event.returnValue = "Write something clever here.."; };
But it is not working in chrome.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML specification states that authors should use the `Event.preventDefault()` method instead of using `Event.returnValue` to prompt the user.

```js
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
  // Cancel the event
  e.preventDefault(); // If you prevent default behavior in Mozilla Firefox prompt will always be shown
  // Chrome requires returnValue to be set
  e.returnValue = '';
});
```

Reference: [WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Callback
    window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
        // Turning off the event
        e.preventDefault();
    }
</script>
```

Some basic explanations about these features

preventDefault: 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp

beforeunload: 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onbeforeunload.asp

Answer (score 0):

It is not advised, but if you want to completely prevent the user from refreshing the page in any way possible you can use:

```js
setInterval(function(){
  window.location.reload();
  window.stop();
},100)
```

Not only will it prevent refreshing, but it will also prevent navigation.