# How to disable/ prevent browser reload icon for a page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, gsp

Browser reload icon functionality should be disabled for a particular page.Even though if it reloads also,the page content should not change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent any form of page refresh using jQuery/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527041/prevent-any-form-of-page-refresh-using-jquery-javascript)

Comment: Thank you for your response

Answer (score 2):

You can disable refresh by using the following code

```
 $(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
        if (e.key == "F5" || e.key == "F11" || 
            (e.ctrlKey == true && (e.key == 'r' || e.key == 'R')) || 
            e.keyCode == 116 || e.keyCode == 82) {

                   e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

Even after this the user can refresh using browser refresh button. If so we can just give a confirmation message using

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        return "Leave this page ?";
    }
```

Comment: TY! Here requirement is disable  browser's reload icon click

Comment: Its not possible.

Comment: Thank you for your response