# JQuery refresh ajax data on browser refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onbeforeunload

is there any method in JQuery or Javascript to prevent the page refresh (F5) and then update only some parts of the page with Ajax?

I tried the code below with no results.

```
 $(window).bind('beforeunload', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //My ajax refresh code
 });
```

Many thanks for your time.

Comment: check out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527041/prevent-any-form-of-page-refresh-using-jquery-javascript

Answer (score 0):

you can try this with below code:

```
$('.update').click(function () {
$.ajax({
url: "",
success: function (s, x) {
$('.yourupdatesection').html(s);
}
});
});
```

> You can add update button in that section and then you will click on
>   it and only that one part will update with ajax