# How can I prevent webpage reloading when a user clicks on the address bar enter using JQuery or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am tying to prevent a webpage reload when the user presses enter on the address bar. Using JQuerys e.preventDefault() method in Google Chrome does not work in the beforeunload method. In general, is this possible to achieve this goal with JQuery or JS or do I need another technique?. If it is possible can someone help me to fix this?

Comment: you can find answer here `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527041/prevent-any-form-of-page-refresh-using-jquery-javascript`

Comment: I have tried this $(window).on('beforeunload', function(event) { ... }); but it doesn"t work. Do I need to return something because I don"t need this in my code. I have tried this here also but it doesn"t work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event.

Answer (score 2):

You simply can't to do it. It is not possible to deal with address bar itself from JavaScript. You can only add the confirmation dialog.

Comment: And what technique (framework, library etc.) should I apply to get this working?

Comment: I have tried to add a confirmation dialog in the beforeunload method but the dialog gets not displayed. Only this method gets printed in the devtools of the browser:
Blocked confirm('LEAVING') during beforeunload.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **You can not.**

Think it this way, When the user hits enter in `address bar`, the user is entering an URL and trying to reach that, And it is handled by the browser only. You can(and should) not block the user from leaving the page. Utmost, you can notify the user before leaving the existing page.

If you are doing this For performance optimization, consider caching the static files.