# How to ask user to confirm page refresh in vue3 composition API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, navigation, vue-router, refresh

I am new ti Vue and I am trying to get my app to ask the user for confimration before a page refresh (manual) can be done. IS this possible?

I know how to get the confirmation when the user clicks another router link.

I used the example here [enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-onbeforerouteleave-navigation-guard-in-vue-3-jsmcr?file=/src/views/Home.vue:361-364) to create this :

```
import { useRouter, onBeforeRouteLeave } from "vue-router";
    const promptExit = ref(true);
   onBeforeRouteLeave((to, from, next) => {
      if (promptExit.value) {
        const answer = window.confirm('Do you really want to leave? you have unsaved changes!')
  if (answer) {
    from()
  } else {
    from(false)
  }
      } else {
        next();
      }
    });
```

But is there a way to have the same effect on a hard page refresh on the browser

Comment: Vue router is totally unrelated to this. It tracks location changes that are made with history API.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527041/prevent-any-form-of-page-refresh-using-jquery-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1